# Turing machines and consistency conceptualization issue?

Tags: logic

I'm reading Kleenes Metamathematics and on the 2nd to last chapter.  I understand Turing machines and for the most part get the idea of the issue with consistency but I'm having a problem keeping tack of all the different ways in which he explains the problems and proofs. I feel that his notation is a little obtuse and the entire idea could be framed in a better context... but anyways. I'm missing some key concept I guess because I get lost when he starts talking about consistency.

All I can do is try to explain how I understand it then someone with enough knowledge(and time/desire) can see where I'm going wrong, so that is what I'll do now:

So, we have a Turing machine. Essentially it is a very simple programmable machine. It is not difficult to understand. The machine has a program p that takes an input a and a "time" x when the machine "computes" the value of a. This is really not much different than real computers. We write programs, supply inputs, and get outputs. Every program essentially can be encoded in to a number.

He represents process by T(p,a,x) which is the output of the machine at time x. Ex T(p,a,x) is true if there is a "stopping time" for the program else false.

He defines N, essentially a program for "arithmetic" using the symbols to do arithmetic and hence fundamental to number theory.

He then constructs a specific type of machine that essentially tries to compute the value of it's own program and asks if the machine stops, i.e., is Ex T(p,a,x) true. If we assume it is true then we can arrive at a contradiction based on the design of the machine.

Here this is suppose to prove that not all inputs of the machine stop or that some programs do not halt for some inputs. We can write a typical modern program that doesn't halt in a similar way but this is proved for number theory(which seems to be the focus). So not all number theoretic processes have "answers" or not all questions about number theoretic propositions have answers/terminate.

He then talks about consistency of proofs of N. That is, if we have a proof of one thing does it prevent the proof of it's negation or vice versa? He says this is true and there are several proofs. I don't quite follow around this stage exactly what is going on even after reading it a few times. I start getting the feeling things are being said but are redundant and I don't know where we are going at this point.

I guess even in his Theorem 2 I'm a bit skeptical. He essentially says that phi_p(p) = phi_p(p) + 1 and this is the contradiction that proves that the machine cannot always compute. But it seems to me that they are actually different phi's being conflated as the same and a "circular process" is created. This is like `A: goto A`. Such program exist but they have no relevance on anything, they are invalid because the machine was not structured correctly to prevent circular references. In some sense is psi(a) is trying to compute itself.

If the point is that no matter how intricate we construct machines this will always occur, then that is fine but why don't we just eliminate all circular sub-programs from being used in any machine?

I guess I feel that if the point has to do with "circular/infinite loops" then why is there so much time invested in explaining this and describing it in a complex fashion? It leads me to believe I must be missing something.

I also don't understand why computing the program as an argument necessarily prevents the machine from running. It suggests something very deep but I know for  fact that for typical computer programs we can easily input the program's binary as an argument(e.g., print(a); then feed the binary our source code in to the program and it will print it out).

On page 248 He defines Ca = Ex T(a,a,x)

then on the next page states (Ex) T(a,a,x) -> {Proof of Ca in N} and {Proof of Ca in N} -> (Ex) T(a,a,x)

But I can't understand this would not be the case from the definition itself. If we have a "stopping time" then clearly we can prove we have a stopping time. He says it can be proven but I have no idea what needs to be proved. (the only different is that in Ca he uses numerals for a and maybe that is what the proof involves)

On p250 he then essentially works in the negation. Again, I don't see the point because if we don't have a "stopping time" then clearly we can't have a proof that it stopped and vice versa.

At the bottom of p252 he says that not C_a is a formula which expresses it's own provability... which again seems obvious because if a program does not terminate then how can we ever prove that it does?

In my mind a machine that stops(in the sense that it has a finite number steps to produce the output value) is equivalent to a proof that it stops(that precisely is what a proof is under this context). If it doesn't stop then there can be no proof of it stopping. Hence why I'm having trouble understanding why he goes through so much trouble to treat them as different which makes me think I'm missing some key aspect.

He says that Consis -> !Ca

IMO this is the first kinda counter intuitive statement(although OTOH it seems almost necessary to have excluded middle some weird topological sense(we need infinity to be able separate things completely).

I'm I in the right ballpark? ;)

Answer (score 3):

This question is a bit all over the place, but let me start with this:

> if a program does not terminate then how can we ever prove that it does?

While Turing showed that this is **in general** impossible (in the precise sense that there is no consistent computably axiomatizable theory which can prove all non-halting facts), in **specific cases** it may be possible, or indeed quite easy. For example, we can just write a program which clearly gets stuck in an infinite loop (something like "while $i==i$, $i+=1$").

This gets to another aspect of the question:

> why don't we just eliminate all circular sub-programs from being used in any machine?

The problem is that non-halting behavior may not be at all obvious. We can for example construct a Turing machine which searches for a counterexample to Fermat's last theorem *(note that checking whether a tuple $(a,b,c,n)$ is a counterexample is something a Turing machine can do)* and halts iff it finds one. We **now** know that this machine will never halt ... but we certainly didn't figure it out with ease!

Non-halting behavior can only be caused by unbounded search (or something morally equivalent to that), but that doesn't mean that all a priori unbounded searches are bad. For example, searching for the next prime might look worryingly unbounded at first, but since we know there are infinitely many primes we know it's not dangerous.

We **can** produce a computation system in which all non-halting phenomena are ruled out - but the cost of doing so is losing Turing-completeness. E.g. the class of primitive recursive functions avoids non-halting behavior, but there are computable functions which are not primitive recursive. If we want a computation system which really does everything it should then we need to accept that amongst the things it can do are things we may think are silly or irrelevant.

- And self-reference alone shouldn't bother you - consider [Quines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)), for example. Part of the takeaway of the various theorems of Godel, Tarski, Turing, Kleene, and others is that self-reference by itself isn't really paradoxical - rather, it's something we can often do (even if we don't want to), and moreover can be a useful tool for identifying things we *can't* do.

---

As to some additional questions like

> He then talks about consistency of proofs of N. That is, if we have a proof of one thing does it prevent the proof of it's negation or vice versa? He says this is true and there are several proofs. I don't quite follow around this stage exactly what is going on even after reading it a few times. I start getting the feeling things are being said but are redundant and I don't know where we are going at this point.

I think asking a separate question is the way to go: trying to cram too many questions into one post isn't a good idea, it just makes it harder to answer coherently.

Comment: I get all that. 1. I cannot figure out how to distinguish halting with a proof of halting. In my mind they are exactly the the same. So all these distinctions seem to meaningless to me. In my mind the proof of something halting is the actual "computation" to check if it does. If it does then it halts and that is the proof and if it doesn't then it doesn't and that is the proof. I guess here I'm not making the distinction of theory and reality? That is, his Ca is literally a real physical check while a proof doesn't necessarily have to run the machine?

Comment: I mean, I feel that any proof of Ca will literally just be running the machine *logically*. In some cases we can deduces that the machine will or will not halt and that simplifies the proof but it's because the machine itself can be simplified. It would be analogous to optimizing code or short circuiting expressions or using induction to prove something... but ultimately they are all the same abstract mathematical object being discussed. I guess though maybe the distinction is being made because that is not necessarily true although it seems that essentially that is what is proven later on?

Comment: 2. Those Quines, IMO, are not true self printing functions. When they print their code and store the code as strings then the string has to include itself as a reference(it could through circular logic in some way but the programs given do not). E.g., those programs will never be able to print themselves out because the string they would have to print would be infinite. exec(s:='print("exec(s:=%r)"%s)') is clearly not the same.The string s is not the same as the problem. So to say they print their own code is absolutely false. In fact, It seems to violate the the theorems we are talking about

Comment: The only way I can think of this being done is for the code to read it's binary code from memory and print that and then it is truly printing itself. E.g., imagine a machine with a single instruction P0 which prints whatever is stored at memory address 0. Then the program "P0" Would print P0. Of course this isn't entirely correct because print itself is code and part of the machine so it would have to print that, but I don't think that is necessarily a problem.

Comment: @Stretto I don't understand your objection to Quines. "those programs will never be able to print themselves out because the string they would have to print would be infinite. " No, what they have to print out is only their own code, not their code *plus their behavior*. "I cannot figure out how to distinguish halting with a proof of halting. In my mind they are exactly the the same." First of all, they're not even the same type of object: a sequence of sentences is a different sort of thing than a sequence of Turing machine configurations.

Comment: For a more serious response, consider a machine which on input $n$ searches through tuples of numbers $<n$, and after having done so outputs $0$ if it's found a counterexample to Fermat's last theorem and outputs $1$ otherwise. With a single proof we can show that this halts on all inputs, without running it in any meaningful sense. So I just don't get what you're saying here.

Comment: Since they're not literally the same thing, the onus is on **you** to give a definition of "running the machine logically" which matches your intuition. Once you provide such a definition we can check whether it does the job, but until then there's no justification for conflating proofs and computations (although they are similar in many deep ways).

Comment: On the wiki page it says: "no input and produces a copy of its own source code as its only output" and the examples given do not produce an *EXACT* copy of it's own source. This is factual, it's obvious. The javascript example, for example, prints out a string. That string is suppose to be an EXACT copy of it's source but it clearly is not. The string in the outer code has a nonempty string in it but the string for the inner code has an empty string! That proves they are different prima facie.

Comment: The source code is containing a string of it's own code, but not all of it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing) go to the javascript example. The outer l and the inner l are different! Wiki says nothing about behavior. The behavior is just to print a string, if that was the case then the strings would not matter. Wiki disagrees with you. The reason they do this, of course, is that it would create a circular loop.  You cannot include the actual source code as a string in it's down code, it is an explicit circular reference. These examples are not true Quines.

Comment: Also, there is  no difference between code and data. That has been well established for quite some time. IMO, it is exactly the opposite. You say that the onus is on me to prove that computation and proof are the same... but I see it as the opposite. You claim to have a proof of something and claim it is about computation and that they are different. The proof is in the pudding. The true proof of anything is that thing. You can claim you have proof that unicorns exist, but the computation is to demonstrate it by showing it. That is always the case. Computation is proof.

Comment: But computation can take on many forms, just as a mathematical object can. The germ of a set of functions is what is relevant, not the specific functions that may not behave. E.g., a computation may fail to produce a finite proof but if it is equivalent to a computation that does(a proof) then they are the same, and treating them differently only conflates finite with infinite. E.g., Your statements about FLT.  E.g., removable discontinuities work this way. say (x^2 - 9)/(x+3). Disc. at -3 but is it really? Semantically no, this is why we simplify the expression.

Comment: So similarly just because we have a finite proof of a computation that may be infinite doesn't at all bother me because it just means that the computation is actually finite but the representation is poorly described. Just like we can write a program that is very inefficient in execution(say by sleeping for 10000 years between every iteration) does not mean that that it is functionally any different than an optimized program. A proof is just a reduction of a computation in to a relatively short number of logical steps so that humans can follow it and be logical certain of the computation.

Comment: It is not different from that computation... it represents semantically the same thing. On the surface they are different, just as technically (x^2 - 9)/(x+3) is different from (x^2-9)^2/(x^2-9) which is different from (x-3)... but clearly, even in elementary math, we have no problem equivocating them, in fact it is necessary. 3*9 is technically different than 27 but we have no problem treating them the same because "under the hood" the represent the same mathematical entity in "value". Symbolically and syntactically they are different, but all that is meaningless human drivel.